# How do you train a FeedForward Supervised Learning NeuralNet?

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

Suppose I am building a Neural Net to play tic-tac-toe. As I understand it, a good design for the net would be 9 input neurons [one for each square in the grid] 3 hidden layer neurons and 9 output neurons [one for each potential move]. Now that the Net is built, how do you read the output of the net?

As I understand it, to train the net, I would send the net the game board [via the inputs] everytime I need it to make a decision. But **how do I obtain that decision**?

Comment: Well, take the output with highest value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The key thing to realize here is that multiple output neural networks change their state to reflect a solution space, but they do not typically give you a hard and fast, final decision.**

Ultimately, a neural net doesnt give you "just one answer" , but rather, it modifies its internal state to reflect a probabilistic landscape of solutions.

If you just want a single answer, then you will have to have a nueral net with only one output node.

**There is no direct, right answer here**

The question you have is actually quite sophisticated - the science of choosing an answer from a nueral net is an entire field of study, in and unto itself :

For some other insights, check out https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10697/methods-for-choosing-a-result-from-a-multiple-output-node-neural-network .\

Also, scan other resources for decision making methods for multiple-output neural nets.

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense, a NN wouldn't work as well if it just spit out stuff on a whim. Thanks for the answer. Do happen to know of any simple [relatively] SL NeuralNetwork tutorials so I can see a practical [in code] example?